# Word that means "characters" but that also applies to animals?

Tags: single-word-requests

The definition of [character](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=character%20define&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=pDEvVpG9OYu80ATurp6YDA):

> **character**
>    2. a person in a novel, play, or film.

Is there a similar word but that also includes animals?

Example sentence:

> In the novel, she meets many peculiar animals and humans.
>   These [...].

Comment: Mammals; taxpayers; people (according to Rudyard Kipling, anyway); units; heroes; morons.

Comment: I think personified animals can be called as "characters" too.

Comment: Ricky-ticky-tavy strikes again.  What a character!

Comment: Characters are characters. A character can be a dog, or a ghost, or a tree, or stone, or a lampshade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Character](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/character)***  is commonly used in the context of comics, by extension I think you can use it referring to a novel or a movie:

> - A person or animal portrayed with a personality in comics or animation: *a cartoon character.* (AHD)

***[Lassie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lassie)***:

> - Lassie is a fictional female ***collie dog character*** created by Eric Knight in a short story expanded to novel length called Lassie Come-Home. (Wikipedia)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term "personae" to call the human and animal characters in a novel.

> personae (*pl. of persona*): the characters in a play, novel, etc. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/persona?s=t)

Answer (score -2):

In any story characters are always humans or personae who can be either flat or round. Animals and inanimates are never called characters except when they are personified or animated in cartoons. If asked of how many characters in a story then animals are not to be counted. If you want a word to refer to animals and humans altogether then use the words living beings or even creatures. It is always better to refer to human beings in a story as characters or personae and to animals as creatures.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think you'll find Lassie is a character in a written short story. "Animals...are never called characters" is factually wrong, although I suppose such a convention might apply to other languages or cultures.

Comment: From [Thomas the Tank Engine Wikia](https://ttte.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Awdry-created_characters): << Awdry-created characters:
This category is for characters created by either Wilbert Awdry or Christopher Awdry: Characters featured in The Railway Series, characters who were only mentioned and characters who did not make it to the television series, such as those modelled by Wilbert for his Mid Sodor Railway layouts.
... Thomas / Gordon / Henry / Edward / James / Percy / Duck / Toby / ... Cranky ... >> And the Troublesome Trucks are real characters.